# Cannot println like this in reduce because of type mismatch (Unit and String) ?

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

I would like to print the content in a file, and the following code is how I did this.

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

object SimpleSpark {
    def main(arg: Array[String]) = {
        val distFile = sc.textFile("/a/path/to/a/file")
        val aClass: MyClass = new MyClass()

        val mappedRDD = aClass.doStuff(distFile)
        mappedRDD.reduce( (a, b) => println(a) )
        // println( mappedRDD.reduce( (a, b) => a + b + "\n" ) )
        // mappedRDD.foreach(println)
}


class MyClass() {
    def doStuff(rdd: RDD[String]) : RDD[String] = {
        val field = "Hello!"
        rdd.map( x => field + x )
    }
}
```

My problem is:

The two commented-out lines of code are working fine, however, this `mappedRDD.reduce( (a, b) => println(a) )` line is getting error like:

```
cliu@cliu-ubuntu:Apache-Spark$ sbt package
[info] Set current project to Simple Project (in build file:/home/cliu/Documents/github/Apache-Spark/)
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /home/cliu/Documents/github/Apache-Spark/target/scala-2.10/classes...
[error] /home/cliu/Documents/github/Apache-Spark/src/main/scala/SimpleSpark.scala:72: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Unit
[error]  required: String
[error]         mappedRDD.reduce( (a, b) => println(a) )
[error]                                            ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 3 s, completed Dec 2, 2015 5:18:24 PM
```

Why `mappedRDD.reduce( (a, b) => println(a) )` is not working?

And why what I printed is a typr of `Unit` instead of `Sting`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `println(a)` returns nothing (`Unit`), whereas `reduce` is actually expecting a `String` to be returned. You should just return `a`:

```
val reduced = mappedRDD.reduce( (a, b) => a )
```

and then you can perform an operation on `reduced` to print your `a`'s:

```
reduced.foreach(println)
```

Comment: Do you mean that `reduce` should always return something?

Comment: Yes. The function `(a, b) => a` expects `a` to be of type `String`. `println(a)` is of type `Unit` so doesn't work there.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to Ben Watson's answer, you could opt to persist your RDD into a file or perhaps into Hive. The thing with using foreach is that you won't see the elements printed out one after the other - you'll get lots of log messages about the tasks performed when retrieving each element before the actual printout. If you don't want to configure logging then simply persist the RDD.